# OneNote Add-in Development: How to navigate to certain page without getting stuck?

Tags: c#, onenote, onenote-api

I am writing an add-in for *OneNote* with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).  It’s function is to navigate to certain page when double-click a node in treeview, which exhibits the structure of OneNote Notebook-Section-Pages hierarchy.

This is what I do:

```
        private void treeView_NodeDbClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode SelectedNode = e.Node;
            string SeletedNodeID = GetSeletedNodeID(SelectedNode).Last();
            try
            {
                _oneNoteApp.NavigateTo(SeletedNodeID);
                this.Dispose();
                this.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to navigate!");            
            }
            
        }
```

But when I double-click the node in the treeview. OneNote appears to get "stuck" whilst the OneNote process in *Task Manager* says:

> not responding.

Any solution for this problem?  It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the lines `this.Dispose();  this.Close()`?

Comment: It is the same.  Actually I add those two lines is due to above mentioned error. But no lucky even added.